# brew install couchdb fails

Tags: couchdb, homebrew

```
brew install couchdb
```

fails with:

```
 ==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=couchdb/1.1.1/apache-couchdb-1.1.1.tar.gz
File already downloaded in /Users/fairview/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/couchdb/1.1.1 --localstatedir=/usr/local/var --sysconfdir
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... build-aux/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/llvm-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /usr/bin/llvm-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for /usr/bin/llvm-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of /usr/bin/llvm-gcc... gcc3
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by /usr/bin/llvm-gcc... /usr/bin/llvm-gcc
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/llvm-gcc) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/llvm-gcc option to reload object files... -r
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from /usr/bin/llvm-gcc object... ok
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /usr/bin/llvm-gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if /usr/bin/llvm-gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for /usr/bin/llvm-gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if /usr/bin/llvm-gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if /usr/bin/llvm-gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if /usr/bin/llvm-gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if /usr/bin/llvm-gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the /usr/bin/llvm-gcc linker (/usr/bin/llvm-gcc) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin11.2.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for JS_NewContext in -lmozjs185... no
checking for JS_NewContext in -lmozjs185-1.0... no
checking for JS_NewContext in -lmozjs... no
checking for JS_NewContext in -ljs... no
checking for JS_NewContext in -ljs3250... no
checking for JS_NewContext in -ljs32... no
configure: error: Could not find the js library.

Is the Mozilla SpiderMonkey library installed?
==> Exit Status: 1
http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/couchdb.rb#L18
==> Environment
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.8.1
HEAD: 7ccf6fedd08f728e1b8e445b6a7c464365d5c6f8
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
Hardware: 8-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.7.2
Kernel Architecture: x86_64
Ruby: 1.8.7-249
/usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
Xcode: 4.2
GCC-4.0: N/A
GCC-4.2: N/A
LLVM: build 2336
Clang: 3.0-211.10.1
MacPorts or Fink? false
X11 installed? true
==> Build Flags
CC: /usr/bin/llvm-gcc => /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
CXX: /usr/bin/llvm-g++ => /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-g++-4.2
LD: /usr/bin/llvm-gcc => /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
CFLAGS: -O3 -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4
CXXFLAGS: -O3 -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/4.8.1.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.2/include
LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/4.8.1.1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.2/lib
MAKEFLAGS: -j8
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/4.8.1.1/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.2/lib/pkgconfig

Error: Failed executing: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/couchdb/1.1.1 --localstatedir=/usr/local/var --sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc --with-erlang=/usr/local/lib/erlang/usr/include --with-js-include=/usr/local/include --with-js-lib=/usr/local/lib
These existing issues may help you:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/9298
Otherwise, please report the bug:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/checklist-before-filing-a-new-issue
We saved the configure log, please gist it if you report the issue:
    ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew/config.log
```

`brew doctor` gives me :

```
We couldn't detect gcc 4.2.x. Some formulae require this compiler.
NOTE: Versions of XCode newer than 4.2 don't include gcc 4.2.x.
```

**Ideas for a solution?** Are there alternative ways for me to do the download? I don't want to install it via MacPorts as homebrew complains when it is installed.

I don't know if I'm going against some sort of etiquette now, seeing as how I've already posted this [at the proper place](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/9298) but I've  gotten no response yet and as I'm desperate to keep going with my vacation-project I'm turning to my fellow StackOverflowians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely it's this?;

configure: error: Could not find the js library.

Is the Mozilla SpiderMonkey library installed?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for development why not use the couchbase single server installer from couchbase.org. This way you get a very recent version of CDB and spare you the trouble of compiling it yourself. Your production setup will be very likely a Linux box where compiling CDB is a lot easier.